# Is there any equivalent for stdcall in GCC?

Tags: gcc, assembly, kernel, stdcall

I'm working on my own kernel using GCC, and when calling C functions from asm code, I have to do `add esp,xx` myself.  After some searching I found that `stdcall` is a Microsoft invention and can't use it in GCC. Is there any handy way to do this work?

Comment: Since you mentioned that it's your own kernel, I've removed references to Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any equivalence of stdcall in linux?
>
> my kernel in a linux environment

Wait, is this your own kernel, or the Linux kernel?  Because if it's your own kernel, it's not Linux any more.

1. If you're working on Linux, you'll want to stick with regular calling conventions and write your assembly to match.
2. If you're working on your own kernel, you can do anything you want.  GCC and Clang both support `stdcall` calling conventions on ix86 processors, e.g.,

   ```
    #define stdcall __attribute__((stdcall))
   ```

   See: [Function Attributes (GCC manual)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm compiling my own kernel with gcc and someone said there is no stdcall in linux gcc. But it works well with your code!