# How to specify stdcall calling convention with gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, stdcall

Using gcc version 4.1.2, targeting Linux, could not figure out how to specify stdcall.

Found lots of seemingly related answers that all say to use the following:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *int)(int);
```

This is not working though.

Comment: The question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054257/is-there-stdcall-in-linux, does not give the needed answer whatsoever, while https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095869/is-there-any-equivalent-for-stdcall-in-gcc for whatever reason was painfully difficult to find while google searching and did not have a fully fleshed out answer.

Comment: The second (I changed the order) listed answer might be useful for anyone researching similar questions in future.

Answer (score 2):

After much searching, I finally found the right answer incidentally to this stack overflow question: [Is there any equivalent for stdcall in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095869/is-there-any-equivalent-for-stdcall-in-gcc)

The bottom line is to do the following (using #define to accomplish this is optional of course)

```
#define STDCALL __attribute__((stdcall))
typedef void (STDCALL *int)(int);
```